# Not able to verify squarespace domain for non-www-prefixed url in firebase

Tags: firebase, dns, squarespace

I have a domain on square space and I am trying to connect my google firebase app to it.

I was able to setup the DNS properties for the www-prefixed url and I have that one working, but when I visit the site with the www-prefix excluded I receive a firebase error saying 'site not found.'

Since I see that it's reaching firebase I've attempted to setup a redirect in firebase to just forward all requests to made to the www-excluded url directly to the www-prefixed url, but firebase needs to verify I own the www-excluded domain first.

So, Firebase instructed me to open the DNS setting in squarespace and add a txt file to verify I own the www-excluded url, which I have done ( which is also part of what I did for the www-prefixed site successfully) but firebase has not been able to verify the site.

Do I need to add additional records in order for this firebase to verify my site?

In order to get the www url working I had to add an @ A record and the www CNAME record for the www-prefixed url in order to get it to verify, but I am not sure how to get this non-prefixed url to work.

Comment: As this likely an internal configuration issue, you should reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) and/or [Squarespace Support](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/requests/new) directly. If the response you get is worth sharing, consider self-answering your question leaving out any sensitive details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When setting up custom domains in Firebase, the tool gives the user different values and instructs the user to update their domain provider's DNS settings

The problem is that these values provided by the firebase tool may need to be adjusted to match what a given domain provider is expecting.

This doc from firebase shows what they expect from different providers and how to update the values.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

For Squarespace domains, they instruct the user to omit the host for all TXT records and A records rather than using what the firebase tool provides.

This enabled me to connect the non-www site as those values were able to be detected immediately ( zero propagation wait time.)

For CNAME records, Firebase instructs the user to put in the entire host `www.???.com`.

However in this doc from Squarespace they instruct the user to only use www for CNAME records. By omitting the rest of the host name firebase was immediately able to verify the domain and proceed to minting an SSL cert.

https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/215744668-Pointing-a-Squarespace-domain

Comment: Many thanks, Michael. This fixed my prob - I think Google's documentation could use some improvement

Comment: Really glad this helped you,  I know it can be uncomfortable not getting it working right away.

Comment: Was struggling with this very same issue over days, very hard to debug when it can take an hour or more to check if a DNS edit stuck. Anywho this solved my issue for the www.domain.com line item in Squarespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just leave app if app.company.com if you are using Squarespace for CNAME and data that comes from firebase.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community! Your answer could be improved - please add more details to your solution and be sure to read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write a good answer.